# Unchecked call to 'isAssignableFrom(Class<?>)'

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Есть такой код

```
void test(Class to) {
  if (to.isAssignableFrom(UUID.class)) {
    ......
}
```

Intellj на такое выдает warning

> Unchecked call to 'isAssignableFrom(Class<?>)' as a member of raw type 'java.lang.Class'

Что нужно изменить, чтобы убрать предупреждение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Входной параметр нужно было определить как generic-тип

```
void test(Class<?> to) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно аннотацию над методом повесить, или целиком над классом, [SuppressWarnings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html), чтобы подобные предупреждения не выдавались:

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
void test(Class to) {
    if (to.isAssignableFrom(UUID.class)) {
        // ......
    }
}
```